# IF Statement In WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sproc that looks like:

```
-- @intUserType int (Passed in from sproc)

IF @intUserType = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE Users.isDeleted = 0
END

IF @intUserType = 4
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE Users.isDeleted = 0
    AND Users.UserType <> 1
END

IF @intUserType = 3
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE Users.isDeleted = 0
    AND Users.UserType IN (1,3,4)
END
```

I would like to shorten it and not use so many select statements, kinda like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE Users.isDeleted = 1
AND
    IF @intUserType = 1
        THEN Users.UserType > 0
    ELSE IF @intUserType = 4
        THEN Users.UserType <> 1
    ELSE IF @intUserType = 3
        THEN Users.UserType NOT IN(1,3,4)
    END
END
```

Thanks for any help.

Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE Users.isDeleted = 0 AND
( 
   (@intUserType = 1) OR
   (@intUserType = 4 AND Users.UserType <> 1) OR 
   (@intUserType = 3 AND Users.UserType IN (1,3,4))
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE @intUserType = 1 AND Users.isDeleted = 0
  OR (@intUserType = 4 AND Users.isDeleted = 0 AND Users.UserType <> 1)
  OR (@intUserType = 3 AND Users.isDeleted = 0 AND Users.UserType IN (1,3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this, just for completeness.  You can build a CASE function to evaluate multiple expressions in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE 
   CASE 
      WHEN @intUserType = 1 AND Users.isDeleted = 0 THEN 1
      WHEN @intUserType = 4 AND Users.isDeleted = 0 AND Users.UserType <> 1 THEN 1
      WHEN @intUserType = 3 AND Users.isDeleted = 0 AND Users.UserType IN (1,3,4) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END = 1;
```